# php redirect to desktop site from mobile

Tags: php, redirect, mobile, desktop

I read alot from this site and try to create redirect to desktop site.
but it keep coming back to mobile site. At first, it was redirected but redirected back to mobile site while desktop site wasn't load completely.

Check the [Full Site](http://vipnet.byethost7.com/index.php) link

Here is my code -

```
$isPhone = preg_match('/' . implode($uaPhone, '|') . '/i', $uaFull);
$isMobile = preg_match('/' . implode($uaMobile, '|') . '/i', $uaStart);

if($isPhone || $isMobile) {
    $_SESSION["mb"]="jaw";
}

if(!isset($_SESSION['desktop'])) {
    $_SESSION['desktop'] = false;
} else if(isset($_GET['desktop']) && $_GET['desktop'] ==yes) {
    $_SESSION['desktop'] = true;
}

if(!$_SESSION['desktop']) {
    if (isset($_SESSION["MB"] )) {
      header ("Location: http://vipnet.byethost7.com/mobile/m.index.html");
    }
}
```

Comment: where you kept mobile redirection in your code?

Comment: in index file ... with seperate header php and footer php files

Comment: so it is not redirecrting to http://vipnet.byethost7.com/mobile/m.index.html right??

Comment: it's redirect to mobile site but i put a link to desktop site at mobile site and cant go back to desktop site from mobile

Comment: i use javascript cookie at first .. it isn't work well too... redirect to mobile site at first and when i go desktop site, can't go back to mobile site or somehow it redirect itself to desktop site and can't go back to mobile site.

Answer (score -1):

add exit after header

```
 header ("Location: http://vipnet.byethost7.com/mobile/m.index.html");
```

to

```
 header ("Location: http://vipnet.byethost7.com/mobile/m.index.html");
 exit();
```

Comment: still going back to mobile site... it load abit desktop site but then redirect back to mobile site ... i think i should find some way to stop the code excute again .. because it's working right at first then go back to normal mobile redirect mode